# Facing Certain Issues Regarding Google Chrome Updates

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, cookies

I am currently working on Chrome browser and always liked it functions and the way it works but after 77th Update, if I am not wrong then I am facing certain issues that spoiled my experiences while working on Chrome. I think this is the best platform to talk about my issues.

1. I am unable to delete my cookies for many websites where I mistakenly submitted my information. Whenever I go to the advanced setting and tick on the box of cookies and history but whenever I click ok then my browser gets hanged and then there is no delete of cookies and history.

I checked with other browsers but this problem is only shown in Chrome especially these days.

2. I am not able to see certain information whenever I go to any banking website or fill payment information whereas other browsers do not show me these issues.

Please help me in this situation. I hope that you will reply to me and solve these issues. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome does not behave like this for most people, so trust me it's not the updates causing the problem. Most likely you have too many tabs open at a time or some of your browser extensions are corrupted. Another issue could be your cache.

I would recommend deleting all of your extensions, and make sure you have a healthy number of tabs open at a time. In addition, try clearing out your cache.

Also, please try to proofread your posts BEFORE posting. There were tons of typos in your post!